# My linq query is not working as expected, what im i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable

I have a datatable i create after reading in a txt file, once i have that datatable, i need to remove rows based on 1 column and a list of values List returnClass(), but after some testing, i found that my LINQ is removing more than expected... so not sure what im doing wrong with the code below.

At first i thought everything was good, because i was working with a large number of records and the numbers were going down with every pass, but now that im working with a small file to debug, i find out that its removing more than it should..

Here is my LINQ query:

```cs
// REMOVES ALL RECORDS WITH A CLASS THAT IS NON-LABEL CLASS                    
var query = from r in d.AsEnumerable()
            where !returnClass().Any(r.Field<string>("Column7").Contains)
            select r;

DataTable output = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
int dtoutputCount = output.Rows.Count;

ToCSV(output, ftype, "filteredclass");
```

Here is my list: (shorten to make this a simple question)

```cs
private List<string> returnClass()
{
    List<string> cl = new List<string>();
    cl.Add("7");
    cl.Add("72");
    return cl;
}
```

My datatable has 100 rows, the column7 has number in it, type string, i need to find each row that has the exact numbers in my list, so if it finds a 7, i dont want it and if it find a 72 i dont want it. BUT if there is a 75, or 17 or 127 those need to stay. And the query above is removing those because it contains the number 7.

How can i remove based on exact matches?

Comment: Use `Equals` instead of `Contains`?

Comment: One helpful piece of info might be to include your sample input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Use `Contains` instead of `Any`?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `List<string> cl = new List<string>();` how often does that line execute? Just once, or multiple times? I am concerned it might execute for every row in `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are actually looking to see if any value in your `returnClass()` list contains the value found in `column7`.  Inside your `Any` function you are using `String.Contains`, and I'm guessing you expect this is a `List.Contains` or something along those lines.

Try this instead (untested):

```
// REMOVES ALL RECORDS WITH A CLASS THAT IS NON-LABEL CLASS                    
var query = from r in d.AsEnumerable()
            where !returnClass().Contains(r.Field<string>("Column7"))
            select r;

DataTable output = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
int dtoutputCount = output.Rows.Count;

ToCSV(output, ftype, "filteredclass");
```

Comment: Looks like this worked, testing now and will report back if any issues, but ive already marked yours as answer.